# Is it possible to create vertical text in PDF width XHtmlRenderer?

Tags: java, css, xhtmlrenderer

Like this one:
[CSS Vertical Text](http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/)

But it uses browser specific CSS extensions, so I'm wondering if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work. I ended up change the page direction.